# Extract all numbers in a string containing ranges and numbers

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that shows different groups of area.

```
+---------------------------------+
|              Area               |
+---------------------------------+
|                       111/01-02 |
|         111/03-06 and 112/07-09 |
|               111/06 and 111/10 |
|    111/11, 112/01 and 112/05-06 |
+---------------------------------+
```

How do I extract all the area codes from the string of sheet 1? For example, from `111/03-05 and 112/07-09` to `111/03`, `111/04`, `111/05`, `112/07`, `112/08`, `112/09`.

The ideal output would be:

```
+---------------------------------+------------+
|          Area String            |    Area    |
+---------------------------------+------------+
|                       111/01-02 |     111/01 |
|                       111/01-02 |     111/02 |
|         111/03-05 and 112/07-09 |     111/03 |
|         111/03-05 and 112/07-09 |     111/04 |
|         111/03-05 and 112/07-09 |     111/05 |
|         111/03-05 and 112/07-09 |     112/07 |
|         111/03-05 and 112/07-09 |     112/08 |
|         111/03-05 and 112/07-09 |     112/09 | 
|               111/06 and 111/10 |     111/06 |
|               111/06 and 111/10 |     111/10 |
|    111/11, 112/01 and 112/05-06 |     111/11 |
|    111/11, 112/01 and 112/05-06 |     112/01 |
|    111/11, 112/01 and 112/05-06 |     112/05 |
|    111/11, 112/01 and 112/05-06 |     112/06 |
+---------------------------------+------------+
```

Thank you!

Edit: Area string table updated that includes a different prefix rather than unified prefix.

Edit2: Added longer area strings for demonstration.

Comment: `=Left($A2, 6)` if your desired output is always the first six characters in your input cells.

Comment: Are your input strings all on separate rows? e.g. `111/01-02` is on a separate row to `111/03-06 and 111/07-09`?

Comment: Alex P, yes, the table of strings is exactly the same as what is shown above (the first table).

Comment: romar, thanks for your comment but what I want to obtain is also, the other values for the same group (e.g. I want to display in separate rows `111/03, 111/04, 111/05, 111/07, 111/08, 111/09` from the group `111/03-05 and 111/07-09`)

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in code comments.

```
Option Explicit

Sub areaFromAreaString()

    Dim a As Variant, z As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long
    Dim split1 As String, split2 As String, split3 As String, comma As String

    'define split delimiters
    split1 = " and "
    split2 = "-"
    split3 = "/"
    comma = ", "

    With Worksheets("sheet3")

        'get areas from worksheet
        a = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

        'prep target array
        ReDim z(1 To 2, 1 To 1) As Variant
        z(1, 1) = "Area String"
        z(2, 1) = "Area"

        'loop through source areas
        For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)

            'homogenize group delimiters
            a(i, 1) = Replace(a(i, 1), comma, split1)

            'primary split loop
            For Each x In Split(a(i, 1), split1)

                'get hi/lo split by hyphen, default to samevalue if no hyphen
                j = Val(Split(Split(x, split3)(1), split2)(LBound(Split(Split(x, split3)(1), split2))))
                k = Val(Split(Split(x, split3)(1), split2)(UBound(Split(Split(x, split3)(1), split2))))

                'fill in gaps
                For m = j To k
                    ReDim Preserve z(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(z, 2) + 1)
                    z(1, UBound(z, 2)) = a(i, 1)
                    z(2, UBound(z, 2)) = Split(x, split3)(0) & split3 & Format(m, "00")
                Next m

            Next x
        Next i

        'stuff values back onto worksheet
        With .Cells(1, "B").Resize(UBound(z, 2), UBound(z, 1))
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = Application.Transpose(z)
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfect! However, what if my area string contains something like this? `(111/03-05 and 112/07-09)` (rather than 111/07-09). The code doesn't work under this condition. Sorry for not mentioning it in the question.

Comment: `111/03-05 and 112/07-09` works fine for me. If you have `(111/03-05 and 112/07-09)` then remove the brackets.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't specify all examples in my question. I have added `111/11, 112/01 and 112/05-06` as an new example.

Comment: Well, I would probably just run a string replace on `a(i, 1)` changing `", "` to `" and "` before the primary split.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
Sub AreaParser()
    Dim Areas As Range, area As Range

    Set Areas = Range("A2:A5")

    For Each area In Areas
        If InStr(area, "and") = 0 Then
            IterateAreas CStr(area), CStr(area)
        Else
            IterateAreas CStr(area), CStr(VBA.Split(area, "and")(0))
            IterateAreas CStr(area), CStr(VBA.Split(area, "and")(1))
        End If
    Next area

End Sub

Sub IterateAreas(original As String, area As String)
    Dim stem As String, low As Integer, high As Integer, rw As Integer

    If InStr(area, "-") = 0 Then   '~~> Case: "111/06"
        stem = VBA.Left$(area, InStr(area, "/") - 1)
        low = VBA.Right$(area, VBA.Len(area) - InStr(area, "/"))
        high = low
    End If

    If InStr(area, "-") <> 0 Then  '~~> Case: "111/01-02"
        stem = VBA.Left$(area, InStr(area, "/") - 1)
        low = VBA.Split(VBA.Right$(area, VBA.Len(area) - InStr(area, "/")), "-")(0)
        high = VBA.Split(VBA.Right$(area, VBA.Len(area) - InStr(area, "/")), "-")(1)
    End If

    rw = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

    For i = low To high
        Range("C" & rw) = VBA.Trim(original)
        Range("D" & rw) = VBA.Trim(stem & "/" & IIf(i < 10, "0" & i, i))
        rw = rw + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Notes**

1. Assumes your input data starts in `A2`
2. Puts your output starting in `C2`

**To run the code:**

1. Press `ALT + F11`
2. `Insert` > `Module`. Cut and paste code
3. In `AreaParser` press `F5`

Comment: Thank you! However the code wouldn't work for area string starting with 112. I have also updated the question accordingly.